# How to apply a rule `round to negative/positive infinity` for binary fractions

Tags: binary, ieee-754

IEEE-754 defines the two rounding rules among others that prescribe to round towards positive infinity or negative infinity. How should I apply these rules for a binary fraction **0.1101** to be rounded to 2 places?

I tried to go by analogy with decimal fractions `0.384` and `-0.384` that need to be rounded to `2` places after the radix point:

**0.384**

- towards positive infinity produces **0.39** (round up)
- towards negative infinity produces **0.38** (round down)

**-0.384**

- towards positive infinity produces **-0.38** (round down)
- towards negative infinity produces **-0.39** (round up)

Now, for the number **0.1101** there are two rounding options **0.11** and **1.00**. If I use the analogy, I get:

- towards positive infinity produces **1.00** (round up)
- towards negative infinity produces **0.11** (round down)

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Might come in handy: https://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/software/ieee/

Comment: @TobiaTesan, thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: was interested in this but it seems like the original document can't be viewed without paying? anyway, seems like what you say is correct by reviewing the [wikipedia page on IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: @NathanMcCoy, yeah, just wanted to be sure